# HTML5 Offline Cache only certain files

Tags: html, offline-caching

I am trying to use the offline cache but only want to cache certain files. The files & pages that I have explicitly specified in CACHE: section of the manifest are all fine. But the browser also always caches files in the 'Master' cache. I don't want these caches, they should always be requested from the server. How can I stop them being cached?

Comment: Easier to answer if you give more informations: structure of your files, manifest, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the pages that are being cached have the manifest attribute on the HTML element?  If so, that would cause them to be cached regardless if you have a specific entry in the CACHE section or not.

Comment: This was the problem. I didn't realise that was how it worked, I assumed adding the manifest to the page would just cause that page to use the items referenced in the manifest, not cache the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this
Files after CACHE MANIFEST will be cached and file after network won't, * means all other files

```
CACHE MANIFEST
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js

NETWORK:
*
```